# Rails create action Ajax returns Template Missing or Unknown Fomat

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, faye, private-pub

I'm trying to implement private_pub on a one-to-one chat app, without private_pub everything works fine just not ideal chat app since no websocket is used for autoupdates.
I tried implementing as on [RailsCasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/316-private-pub) of private_pub but i am getting either template missing or unknown format.
Here is my code:

Routes

```
  resources :conversations do
    resources :messages
  end
```

I have a button in my user show page to start a chat(which creates/uses a conversation and shows up a conversation show page like a one to one chat box on facebook/gchat , a conversation has many messages):

```
<% unless current_user == @user %>
    <%= link_to "Send Message", conversations_path(:sender_id => current_user.id , :recipient_id => @user.id ), :method => :post, class: "btn btn-success btn-xs start-conversation" %>
<% end %>
```

Conversation Controller

```
class ConversationsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  layout false

  def create
    if Conversation.between(params[:sender_id],params[:recipient_id]).present?
      @conversation = Conversation.between(params[:sender_id],params[:recipient_id]).first
    else
      @conversation = Conversation.create!(conversation_params)
    end
    @conversation.save!
    redirect_to @conversation
  end

  def show
    @conversation = Conversation.find(params[:id])
    @reciever = interlocutor(@conversation)
    @messages = @conversation.messages
    @message = Message.new
  end

  private
  def conversation_params
    params.permit(:sender_id, :recipient_id)
  end

  def interlocutor(conversation)
    current_user == conversation.recipient ? conversation.sender : conversation.recipient
  end
end
```

Convesation Show View

```
    <% content_for :bottom do %>
    <%= subscribe_to conversation_path(@conversation) %>
<% end  %>
<div class="chatboxhead">
  <div class="chatboxtitle">
    <i class="fa fa-comments"></i>

    <h1><%= @reciever.username %> </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="chatboxoptions">
    <%= link_to "<i class='fa  fa-minus'></i> ".html_safe, "#", class: "toggleChatBox", "data-cid" => @conversation.id %>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <%= link_to "<i class='fa  fa-times'></i> ".html_safe, "#", class: "closeChat", "data-cid" => @conversation.id %>
  </div>
  <br clear="all"/>
</div>
<div class="chatboxcontent">
  <% if @messages.any? %>
      <%= render @messages.reverse %>
  <% end %>
</div>
<div class="chatboxinput">
<%= form_for([@conversation, @message], :remote => true) do |f| %>

      <%= f.text_area :body, class: "chatboxtextarea", "data-cid" => @conversation.id %>
      <%= f.submit " Send", class: "btn btn-primary btn-xs"%>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Message Controller

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, only: [:create]

  def create
    @conversation = Conversation.find(params[:conversation_id])
    @message = @conversation.messages.build(message_params)
    @message.user_id = current_user.id
    @message.save!

    @path = conversation_path(@conversation)

  end


  private

  def message_params
    params.require(:message).permit(:body)
  end
end
```

Message's message partial

```
#_message.html.erb    
<li class="<%=  self_or_other(message) %>">
      <div class="avatar">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
      </div>
      <div class="chatboxmessagecontent">
        <p><%= message.body %></p>
        <time datetime="<%= message.created_at %>" title="<%= message.created_at.strftime("%d %b  %Y at %I:%M%p") %>">
          <%= message_interlocutor(message).username %> <%= message.created_at.strftime("%H:%M %p") %>
        </time>
      </div>
    </li>
```

Message's create view

```
#create.js.erb    
<% publish_to @path do %>
    var id = "<%= @conversation.id %>";
    var chatbox = $(".chatboxcontent");
    var sender_id = "<%= @message.user.id %>";
    var reciever_id = $('meta[name=user-id]').attr("content");

    chatbox.append("<%= j render( partial: @message ) %>");
    chatbox.scrollTop(chatbox[0].scrollHeight);

    if (sender_id != reciever_id) {
        chatBox.chatWith(id);
        chatbox.children().last().removeClass("self").addClass("other");
        chatbox.scrollTop(chatbox[0].scrollHeight);
        chatBox.notify();
    }
    <% end %>
```

On Message Controller, create action the above code results "Missing Template" and if I put a respond_to as:

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render 'create.js.erb' }
  end
```

it results "Unknown Format"

Comment: Are you missing `remote: true` param for the link?

Comment: not looking for ajax on the link , only on form !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs when you have not added `jquery_ujs` file. You only included the jquery file.

So you need to add both files manually in you view or require them in `application.js` or any other file which you are using for specific layout.

Depending upon your scenario, you can follow 1st or 2nd solution.

1st solution:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :jquery, :jquery_ujs %>
```

on your conversation show page.

2nd solution:

remove the `"layout false"` on your conversation controller